# how to delete the recently created records in account object using visualforce apex controller

Tags: apex, visualforce

Iam using SAVE and DELETE Buttons in Visualforce page. And when i click the SAVE button it will be insert in account object.But How to delete the same record(when i click the DELETE button). How is it possible, Plese Help me.

Comment: Is this a visualforce page where there is a list of Accounts and associated buttons with them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this way Also.....

```
    public Account ac;
    public void Create(){

        ac = new Account(name='MyAccount');
        insert ac;

    }
    public void delete(){
       if(ac.id! = null){ 
        delete ac;
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use standard controller action to do this. Use

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!delete}" value="Delete"/>
```

to delete the record currently in context.

For this to work, you should pass ?id=001xxxxxxxxxxxx at the end of your url.

**Refer:** [Using Standard Controller Actions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_std_actions.htm)

Hope it hleps.